# Qt5: cross-thread data sharing

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt5

I have a main application thread where I create another thread:

```
QThread* TxThread = new QThread;
TxFTDI* Tx = new TxFTDI();
Tx->moveToThread(TxThread);
```

Then, under some condition, in one of the main thread functions I create object:

```
Ftdi* ftdiChA = new Ftdi;
```

where ftdi device information are stored (handler, serial number, description, etc.). When it is created I would like to use that object data (at least handler) in `Tx` thread.

I can't find working solution. Could you please help?

Comment: Sharing data between threads is really easy, since all threads in a single process shares the same memory. The problem is usually the *synchronization* of the data, so no two threads try to write the data simultaneously, or one try to write while another try to read. This is where semaphores, mutexes, atomics and conditional variables all comes into play. This is also a long solved problem, and there should be enough examples all over the Internet to help you figure out how to do it with any framework or API supporting the basic thread-synchronization primitives.